# Complicated AJAX update with two select elements

Tags: html, javascript

I have a form with two select elements where users can select a product variant (for example red, green, blue shirt) and the quantity.

When changing the variant/quantity, I do a AJAX request to get the price.

The complicated part is: each variation has its own price and its own quantities. For example red shirts are 10 USD and at a minimum quantity of 5 (10, 15…). Green shirts are 15 USD but quantity starts at 3 (6, 9…).

(Color/shirt just an example, real products are control units for streetlights :-)

The problem is, when the default is 'red' and '5' and I change to 'green' the price shows 75 USD (AJAX query was green+5). But green only has quantities of 3, 6, 9 etc.

I could return the minimum quantity from my AJAX request, but then the user can't update the price when changing the quantity select.

Only solution I see is make two doSubmit() functions and two submitAjax(). But this would mean I have a lot of duplicate code.

HTML

```
<form action="" id="product_selection">
    <select name="product_variation">
        <option value="r">Red</option>
        <option value="g">Green</option>
        <option value="b">Blue</option>
    </select>
    <select name="product_quantity">
        <option value="">10</option>
        <option value="">20</option>
        <option value="">30</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
// Product variation, quantity select dropdown
var product_selection = document.querySelector('#product_selection');
var product_variation = document.querySelector('#product_variation');
var product_quantity = document.querySelector('#product_quantity');

// Event listener to submit the form on change
product_selection.addEventListener('submit', submitAjax);
product_variation.addEventListener('change', doSubmit);
product_quantity.addEventListener('change', doSubmit);

// Submit form
function doSubmit(event) {
    product_selection.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit')); // product_selection.submit();
}

// Handle ajax submit
function submitAjax(event) {

    // Stop default form submit
    event.preventDefault();

    // Ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: '/static/public/ajax/get_product_data.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#product_selection').serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
            if (result == 0) {
                alert('Sorry');
            } else {
                setProductData(result);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
            alert('Sorry');
        }
    })
}

// Update product details
function setProductData(result) {
    $('#product_price').html(result.price_gross);

    // Remove current quantity options
    var product_quantity = document.getElementById("product_quantity");
    for(i = product_quantity.options.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        product_quantity.remove(i);
    }
    // … reapply new quantity options
    var c = 0;
    for (var i = result.minimum; i <= result.maximum; i+=result.graduation) {
        product_quantity.options[c] = new Option(i + ' ' + pwjs.product.unit, i);
        if (result.product_quantity == i) {
            var setselectedIndex = c;
        }
        c++;
    }
    // product_quantity.selectedIndex = setselectedIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to do this in steps so `product_variation.addEventListener('change', doSomethingElse);`

then your select would be something like:

```
<select name="product_variation">
    <option data-increment="5" value="r">Red</option>
    <option value="g">Green</option>
    <option data-increment="3" value="b">Blue</option>
</select>
```

then when the `product_variation` changes `doSomethingElse` would rebuild the `product_quantity` select to take the `increment` value of the selected `product_variation`

Answer (score 0):

As far I can see, you are using jQuery. So, Ill give you an example of how you can achieve this.

#### HTML

First of all, don't forget to specify the values for your select options, your values for product_quantity were empty. Also, I'd recommend to you that you create an extra option tag to be the default selected option and be able to validate your form later on.

```
<form action="" id="product_selection" name="product_selection">
    <select name="product_variation">
        <option value="">Select color</option>
        <option value="r">Red</option>
        <option value="g">Green</option>
        <option value="b">Blue</option>
    </select>
    <select name="product_quantity">
        <option value="">Select quantity</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

#### JavaScript

As for JavaScript, I'll recommend you to add the event listener for your last input, which is the product_quantity.

```
$("#product_selection").submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var inputs = document.product_selection;
   if( inputs.product_variation.value != "" && inputs.product_quantity.value != "" ){
     $.ajax({
        url: '/static/public/ajax/get_product_data.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#product_selection').serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
            if (result == 0) {
                alert('Sorry');
            } else {
                setProductData(result);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
            alert('Sorry');
        }
      });
   }
});
```